# Curator not deleting older index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have an index named 'locations' where I pushed some data few days ago. I want to delete all data older than 1 day.
My config looks like -

actions:
1:

```
action: delete_indices

description: >-

  Delete indices older than 10 days (based on index name), for locations
  prefixed indices.

options:
  ignore_empty_list: True
  disable_action: True
filters:
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: prefix
  value: locations
- filtertype: age
  source: creation_date
  direction: older
  unit: days
  unit_count: 1
- filtertype: count
  count: 1
options: 
  disable_action: false
  ignore_empty_list: true
  allow_ilm_indices: true
```

---

However, when I run this config I get below -

2021-04-30 03:33:35,639 DEBUG          curator.indexlist        iterate_filters:1244 Pre-instance: ['locations']

2021-04-30 03:33:35,639 DEBUG          curator.indexlist        filter_by_count:928  Filtering indices by count

2021-04-30 03:33:35,639 DEBUG          curator.indexlist           working_list:237  Generating working list of indices

2021-04-30 03:33:35,639 DEBUG          curator.indexlist       __not_actionable:38   Index locations is not actionable, removing from list.

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 DEBUG          curator.indexlist            __excludify:58   Removed from actionable list: locations is 1 of specified count of 1.

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 DEBUG          curator.indexlist        iterate_filters:1246 Post-instance: []

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 DEBUG     curator.actions.delete_indices               **init**:612  master_timeout value: 30s

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 DEBUG                curator.cli         process_action:103  Doing the action here.

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 DEBUG          curator.indexlist       empty_list_check:226  Checking for empty list

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 INFO                 curator.cli                    run:202  Skipping action
"delete_indices" due to empty list: <class 'curator.exceptions.NoIndices'>

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 INFO                 curator.cli                    run:225  Action ID: 1, "delete_indices" completed.

2021-04-30 03:33:35,655 INFO                 curator.cli                    run:226  Job completed.

---

What configuration am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Curator manages whole indices only. Curator either deletes an index, or it doesn't. It cannot delete data from *within* an index.

However, one potential way to accomplish what you seek would be to use Elasticsearch's [`delete_by_query` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/docs-delete-by-query.html). However, I strongly discourage this if you are indexing a continuous stream of time-based data (e.g. logs, metrics, etc.). It is much more efficient to use [rollover indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/indices-rollover-index.html) and delete the old indices as a whole. Think of the difference in impact to your Elasticsearch cluster as being the same difference between a SQL `DROP TABLE` vs. a `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE...` statement. In the former, a single statement deletes the entire table as a single operation, but in the latter it could be tens of thousands of individual operations.  A `delete_by_query` is similar in Elasticsearch terms, and there are other negative impact reasons in pursuing that if it can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already saw about 'delete_by_query'. Will check rollover_indices.